# iOS: error when running project on real device

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, architecture, lib

I included an external C++ library for my iOS project. This library was compiled and linked with my project from this: http://github.com/chili-epfl/chilitags/

Then when I run the project on simulator, it compiles. But when I run the project  on real device like iPhone7, it fails.

The error was clear:

```
warning: ignoring file /usr/local/lib/libchilitags.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /usr/local/lib/libchilitags.dylib
```

Because the lib file was ignored, the functions I used all caused fatal link error.

The reason was clear but I don't know what to do. iPhone7 was arm64 architecture but the file was x86_64 architecture and we have to run it on real devices.

So, what should I do so that I can run x86_64 libs on arm64 real devices? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> BSo, what should I do so that I can run x86_64 libs on arm64 real devices?

The problem is in different processor instruction set used in `x86` and `arm64`.

So, you should compile the library for `arm64` or find it already compiled for target architecture.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the problem. But I have no idea how to compile the whole external library into arm64 architecture. Is is something to do with CMake Cross-compiling?